# How to write Copyright in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to help a friend for his wordpress. Problem is, I'm pretty much totally unfamiliar with how php works. I have not written this code but as I have basic idea about html and css, I tried to fix it but still without success. 
The result is : ; . Copyright © 2015 AABB. All Rights Reserved. 
But I want: Copyright © 2015 AABB. All Rights Reserved.

1. I do not find how to remove „ ;. „.
2. If I delete:

   ```
   Copyright &copy;
   <?php echo date("Y")." "; ?>
   <?php bloginfo('name')." "; ?>.
   All Rights Reserved.
   ```

   No copyright will be shown on the footer.

The code is as below:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Perfekto
 * @since Perfekto 1.0
     */
    ?>
        </div><!-- end .pad_container -->

        <div class="pagination-bg"></div>
        <div class="pagination-bottom"></div>
    <div id="footer">

            <div id="foot-full">

                <?php get_sidebar('footerfull');?>

            </div><!-- end #footfull -->


            <div id="foot-full2">

                <?php get_sidebar('footerfull2');?>

            </div><!-- end #foot-full2 -->

            <div id="foot-col1">
                <?php get_sidebar('footer1');?>
            </div><!-- end #foot-col1 -->
            <div id="foot-col2">
                <?php get_sidebar('footer2');?>
            </div><!-- end #foot-col2 -->
            <div id="foot-col3">
                <?php get_sidebar('footer3');?>
            </div><!-- end #foot-col3 -->
            <div class="clear"></div>

        </div><!-- end #footer -->  
        <div id="footer-copyright">
            <div id="copyright">
<?php /* $foot= stripslashes(get_option('templatesquare_footer')) */ ?>
                <?php /* if($foot==""){ */?>
                <?php /* _e('Copyright', 'templatesquare'); */ ?> <!-- &copy -->
                    <?php /* bloginfo( 'name' ); */ ?></a>;
                <?php
                /*
                 global $wpdb;

                $post_datetimes = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT YEAR(min(post_date_gmt)) AS firstyear, YEAR(max(post_date_gmt)) AS lastyear FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_date_gmt > 1970");
                if ($post_datetimes) {
                    $firstpost_year = $post_datetimes[0]->firstyear;
                    $lastpost_year = $post_datetimes[0]->lastyear;
                    $copyright = $firstpost_year;
                    if($firstpost_year != $lastpost_year) {
                        $copyright .= '-'. $lastpost_year;
                    }
                    $copyright .= ' ';





            echo '<a href="'.home_url( '/').'">'.get_bloginfo('name') .'</a>';
                }
                */
            ?>. <?php /* _e('All rights reserved.', 'templatesquare'); */ ?>

                <?php /* }else{ */ ?>
                <?php /* echo $foot; */ ?>
                <?php /* } */ ?>


Copyright &copy;
<?php echo date("Y")." "; ?>
<?php bloginfo('name')." "; ?>.
All Rights Reserved.    


            </div>
            <div id="footermenu">

            <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                  'container'       => 'ul', 
                  'menu_class'      => '',
                  'menu_id'         => '', 
                  'depth'           => 1,
                  'sort_column'    => 'menu_order',
                  'theme_location' => 'footmenu' 
                  )); 
            ?>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end #footer-copyright -->
    </div><!-- end #container -->
</div><!-- end #frame -->
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-31480559-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> Cufon.now();</script> <!-- to fix cufon problems in IE browser -->
    <?php

        wp_footer();
    ?>
    <?php $google = stripslashes(get_option('templatesquare_google'));?>
    <?php if($google=="false"){?>
    <?php }else{?>
    <?php echo $google; ?>
    <?php } ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually it shows the current year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have random punctuation all over the place, which is leading to the issue.

```
<?php /* bloginfo( 'name' ); */ ?></a>;
                                      ^----here

?>. <?php /* _e('All rights reserved.', 'templatesquare'); */ ?>
  ^----and here
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.

Answer (score 0):

You have a trailing ';' and '.'.

Culprits are the ';' after your  tag next to bloginfo('name') - Line 46

and the '.' before your commented out _e('All rights reserved ... - Line 68

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.

Answer (score -2):

```
© <?php
    $copyYear = 2008; // Set your website start date
    $curYear = date('Y'); // Keeps the second year updated
      echo $copyYear . (($copyYear != $curYear) ? '-' . $curYear : '');
  ?> Copyright
```

All these code are working